# jQuery validation not functioning on second pass

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a password update form that uses jQuery validation for three fields.  The validation functions correctly the first time the form is displayed and, if the entered data validates, a success message is displayed along with the form a second time.  If the user clicks the submit button the second time the form is displayed, the form is submitted without any validation.

One thing that should be noted, although I'm not sure it matters, is that there are validation rules for several forms in the same js file, because the forms are all located on the same page and displayed via show/hide js.

Also, validation for my other form (a reservation form) does not function either when the success message is displayed, but as soon as the success message above the password update form is replaced with any other data the all validation functions properly.

Any idea why, when the success message is displayed above the password update form, the validation for the password update form doesn't function on the next submit?

On success the following output is generated:

```
$output = '<p class="message">Your password has been updated.</p>
```

and then prepended to the following:

```
    <!-- php snippet -->

   $output .=    '<form method="post" action="thispage.php" method="post" name="updatepassword" id="updatePasswordForm">
       <input type="hidden" value="updatePassword" name="task">
       <table class="members">
       <tr>
       <td class="formlabel top">Current Password: </td>
       <td><input name="currentpassword" id="currentpassword" type="password" size="30" class="inputbox" placeholder="Your Current Password"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td class="formlabel top">New Password: </td>
       <td><input name="newpassword" id="newpassword" type="password" size="30" class="inputbox" placeholder="Your New Password"></span></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td class="formlabel top">Re-enter New Password: </td>
       <td><input name="newpassword2" id="newpassword2" type="password" size="30" class="inputbox" placeholder="New Password Again for Validation"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td colspan="2" class="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Update Password"></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
       </form>  ';

    <!-- end snippet -->
```

and displayed:

```
    echo $output;
```

The js:

```
    $().ready(function() {
      // validate reservation form on keyup and submit
      $("#ReservationForm").validate({
        rules: {
          datepicker: {
            required: true
          },
          number: {
            required: true,
            digits: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
          datepicker: {
            required: "Enter the date<br />Use the calendar to select the date"
          },
          number: {
            required: "Enter your number",
            digits: "Enter only digits"
          }
        }
      });

      // validate select segments form on keyup and submit
      $("#selectSegments").validate({
        rules: {
          'segment[]': {
            required: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
          'segment[]': {
            required: "Select at least one segment"
          }
        }
      });

      // validate update password form on keyup and submit
      $("#updatePasswordForm").validate({
        rules: {
          currentpassword: {
            required: true,
            remote: "remote/check.current.password.php"
          },
          newpassword: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
          },
          newpassword2: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            equalTo: "#newpassword"
          }
        },
        messages: {
          currentpassword: {
            required: "Enter your current password",
            remote: "Your password is incorrect"
          },
          newpassword: {
            required: "Enter your new password",
            minlength: "Enter at least 6 characters"
          },
          newpassword2: {
            required: "Reenter your new password",
            minlength: "Enter at least 6 characters",
            equalTo: "New passwords don't match"
          }
        }
      });
    });

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54184267/edit) and then create a a snippet `[<>]` to give us a [mcve]

Comment: I solved this problem, and it was a problem of my own making.  When the page loaded with the success message, that bit of php failed to include the jQuery code and libraries required.  As soon as I added that back in, it worked perfectly.

Thanks to anyone that may have put in time on this.

Comment: Please delete this question since it is not useful to others

Comment: Voting to close/delete as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score -1):

This issue is resolved.

When the page loaded with the success message, I failed to include the jQuery code and libraries required. As soon as I added that back in, it worked perfectly.